# MSBuild failing on Automated Test project

Tags: msbuild, vs-unit-testing-framework

I just added an automated test project to my C# solution and checked it into my build server.

When the build script runs using MSBuild (.NET Framework 3.5), it gives me several errors (such as the following):

```
**cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

**.cs(21,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**.cs(73,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**.cs(73,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**.cs(14,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**.cs(14,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClassAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

When I run the .NET 3.5 msbuild on my computer, it builds correctly.

The build server does not have .NET 4.0 on it, and stepping it up is not an option.  Can anyone suggest what could be causing the difference and what I can do to get the test project building successfully ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed Visual Studio on your build server?

Comment: No, I don't have Visual Studio on my build server.  I thought mstest (which I didn't get to executing yet) was part of the .NET framework.

Is there any way to build and run the automated tests without having Visual Studio on the build box, or will I need to have the tests in a separate solution and only run them on my local box?

Comment: I believe you have to have the test portions installed on the test server; although [I ran into other, still unsolved, problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10142647/50447)

Comment: Change the test framework to Nunit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above, the easiest thing to do is to install the appropriate version of Visual Studio on your build server to get all of the MSTest dependencies. This is what is typically done.

If for whatever reason you can't do that, the following page shows how to get your dependencies available without the VS2008 install:

http://www.shunra.com/shunrablog/index.php/2009/04/23/running-mstest-without-visual-studio/

Comment: I actually went with changing my test framework to NUnit, but thanks.

Comment: This link seems to go to HP??

Comment: Interesting... shunra.com seems to redirect to HP.